# using Form to retrieve dropdownlist value

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist which has both text and value .When I try to retrieve the data from Page.Request.Form["ID1"] I am getting back the value  and not the text ..Is there a way I can get both of these .

```
<select id="ID1">
<option Value="1">
Test
</option>
<Option Value="2">
Test2
</Option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Curious is there any reason you are using the Page.Request.Form? You could retrieve it from the code behind by its ID and grab both

Comment: The dropdown list control is generated dynamically on the client side..so I cannot use this technique .

Comment: Curious - do you have any control over the client side at all?

Comment: Yeah I have a table and inside that table I am generating rows and adding the dropdown list dynamically..The table is in the server side,

Comment: I updated my answer based upon the new criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my answer based upon the criteria

I'm kinda writing this off the cuff so I apologize if there are syntax errors - hopefully you get the general idea

Since you have control over the client side.. you could pass over the form text / value like this

```
<select name="mySelect">
<option value="myName1:myValue1">myName1</option>
<option value="myName2:myValue2">myName2</option>
<option value="myName3:myValue3">myName3</option>
</select>
```

Then... server side you could do something like this...

```
var mySelect = Page.Request.Form["mySelect"].ToString();
var myText = mySelect.Split(":".ToCharArray()).First();
var myValue = mySelect.Split(":".ToCharArray()).Last();
```

Comment: The dropdown list control is generated dynamically on the client side..so I cannot use this technique .

Answer (score 0):

**Only the value is post back on the form**.

Using the value you can find the text in the list, that you need to have save/keep, either on viewstate, either keep it on Drop Down list box. If you can not use them, then one other solution is to keep all your data that you wish to get on the value, and split them later.

Comment: so meaning there is no way to get to the text property directly if we have a value property defined in a dropdownlist using Request.Form

Comment: @user505210 Yes this is. You can see all the items that you have on the form, just see the `Page.Request.Form`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way this can be done.

During initialisation of the webcontrol, in the code behind, store the dropdownlist in a member variable so you keep a reference to it, and populate it's Items collection during initialisation.

Then get the posted back value (key) using Request.Form(ddl.UniqueID) also during initialisation.

Use the key to look up the item in the drop down list eg.

```
dim selectedValue as string = Request.Form(ddl.UniqueID)
dim theItem as ListItem = Nothing
If Not IsNothing(ddl.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue)) Then
  theItem = ddl.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue)
  dim strText as string = theItem.Text
End If
```